# Does Mojave 10.14 support core audio FireWire?

Tags: audio, firewire

I would like to upgrade from high sierra but afraid my mackie 1640i mixer will not be recognized by core audio. Thank you.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/449077/mac-kernelpanic-using-firewire-device

Comment: Heya - thank you so much - I’ve checked the link and it seems in good to go as I do have an upgraded metal gpu in my mid 2010 macpro - I’m cloning my startup disk and will install 10.14 Mojave on external had just to be sure —

Answer (score 1):

I can verify that the Mackie 1640i was recognized by mid-2010 Mac Pro with Metal capable GPU running Mojave macOS 10.14 (thanks to information provided by Tetsujin).